# Expectation of the absolute difference of two i.i.d Normal distributions

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Let X and Y be iid $\sim Normal(0,1)$

I am interested in finding $E|X-Y|$.

Based on some simulations, I know that it is approximately 1. However, I don't know how to make that appear analytically.

Comment: I edited the title to be more directly tied to what is being asked here.

Comment: user164144 and @MatthewDrury .... note that $X-Y$ is not a difference of two *distributions*, it's the difference of two random variables. The distinction is important!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I fixed my wording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables, then $X - Y$ is normal.

$$ X - Y \sim Normal(0, \sqrt{2}) $$

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907923/expectation-of-an-absolute-value-that-is-the-standard-normal), the expectation of the absolute value of a standard normal is:

$$ E \left[ | X | \right] = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} $$

So for the difference

$$ E \left[ | X - Y | \right] = \sqrt{2} E \left[ | X | \right] = \sqrt{\frac{4}{\pi}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} $$

In R, from a simulation

```
> X <- rnorm(10000)
> Y <- rnorm(10000)
> Z <- mean(abs(X - Y))
> Z
[1] 1.124015
```

And numerically

```
> 2/sqrt(pi)
[1] 1.128379
```