# What is the rationale of using 2.66 times moving range for control limits in individual control charts?

Tags: standard-deviation, quality-control

The Wikipedia says "If the data are normally distributed with standard deviation $\sigma$  then the expected value of $\overline {MR}$ is $d_{{2}}\sigma =2\sigma /{\sqrt  \pi }$."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shewhart_individuals_control_chart

Are the control limits based on moving range robust to violation of the normal distribution assumption?

Comment: I replaced \`\`\` by \$ and removed the duplication of formulas inherent in the way Wikipedia does it.  Note that in the same article it says "The value $2.66$ is obtained by dividing $3$ by the sample size-specific $d_2$ anti-biasing constant for $n=2$, as given in most textbooks on statistical process control (see, for example, Montgomery)", which adds a little information about where it comes from

Comment: thanks! Realize I should use $ instead of ``` for formulae now. This post helps explain the convergence of 2.66MR to 3sigma.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288486/expectation-of-the-absolute-difference-of-two-i-i-d-normal-distributions